# Crystal Reports Cross-tab with mix of Sum, Percentages and Computed values

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, crosstab

Being new to crystal, I am unable to figure out how to compute rows 3 and 4 below.

Rows 1 and 2 are simple percentages of the sum of the data.

Row 3 is a computed value (see below.)

Row 4 is a sum of the data points (NOT a percentage as in row 1 and row 2)

Can someone give me some pointers on how to generate the display as below.

My data:

```
2010/01/01 A 10
2010/01/01 B 20
2010/01/01 C 30

2010/02/01 A 40
2010/02/01 B 50
2010/02/01 C 60

2010/03/01 A 70
2010/03/01 B 80
2010/03/01 C 90
```

I want to display

```
                        2010/01/01    2010/02/01     2010/03/01
                        ==========    ==========     ==========
[ B/(A + B + C)     ]   20/60         50/150         80/240      <=== percentage of sum
[ C/(A + B + C)     ]   30/60         60/150         90/240      <=== percentage of sum
[ 1 - A/(A + B + C) ]   1 - 10/60     1 - 40/150     1 - 70/240  <=== computed
[ (A + B + C)       ]   60            150            250         <=== sum
```

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a SQL data source, I suggest deriving each of the output rows' values (ie. [B/(A + B + C)], [C/(A + B + C)], [1 - A/(A + B + C)] and [(A + B + C)]) per date in the SQL query, then using Crystal's crosstab feature to pivot them into the output format desired.

Crystal's crosstabs aren't particularly suited to deriving different calculations on different rows of output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will give it a go but I was kind of hoping that it might be possible without resorting to SQL manipulation.  (I am using Oracle)